# Getting rid of white space at the bottom of the page of the website when at test server

Tags: html, css

It seems that there's no similar problem as mine that I can find in the Internet. So my problem is a huge white space at the bottom of the website that I am currently developing. It only appears after I uploaded it to the server that I have but it isn't when I test it in my WAMP server. What could be causing it? I double checked my CSS and can't find the one that I think causes the problem.

The following image shows the bottom of the page when it's tested in localhost:

http://i59.tinypic.com/rtnqqr.png

This is the image that shows what the bottom of the page looks like after being uploaded to a test server:

http://i59.tinypic.com/sg7las.png

In case you need the exact website:

http://www.bagongbayani.url.ph

Notice that there's already a white space at the bottom of the page. What do you think causes that to happen?

I am using Unsemantic Responsive Grid Framework for that site.

**NOTE:** Don't resize the screen to a smaller one. I am not yet finished with the design of the mobile view.

Comment: *So my problem is a huge white space at the bottom* **I am more concerned about the right instead**

Comment: Would you mind including a screenshot of the site as you see it, with the whitespace? On my end, it looks exactly the same as your localhost screencap. Unless I try resizing the window, then the Javascript seems to get a bit surprised and does not recalculate the dynamic heights correctly. Or unless your window is sized quite narrow, in which case, it switches to a mobile-only version that converts the entire lower region to white. A screenshot will be helpful either way.

Comment: body {margin:0;}
get rid of a lot of those margin:-10px; and I'm not seeing the gap.

Comment: Since you're not asking about that space to the right, I won't bug you about it anymore than the others. Just know that setting #links-wrap to a width of 100% the screen + 150px extra margin is producing a lot of side space (in addition to the smaller complex margins and positioning going on elsewhere).

Comment: @DanielRippstein - I already added a screenshot that shows the whitespace I'm seeing when uploaded to a web server. At first it doesn't show but after visiting it again it will show.

Answer (score 0):

The white space appears at the bottom of the layout when the page contents are not as tall as the viewport. Thus you get the body background showing at the bottom. There are fancy fixes for this, but really, the easiest and most practical solution (in my view) is to apply the footer background color (in this case, an image) to the body itself:

```
body {background-image: url(../images/zwartevilt.png);}
```